# Variadic generic types in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

I'd like to make a function in TypeScript that takes an array of constructor functions and returns a corresponding array of instances. See code below.

Note that the `getArray` method is wildly incorrect, it is just an attempt to convey my intent.

Is this possible in any form or is it beyond the capabilities of TypeScript's type engine?

```
class T1 {}
class T2 {}
class T3 {}
type AnyCon = new() => any;

function getOne<T_Con extends AnyCon>(con: T_Con): InstanceType<T_Con> {
  return new con();
}

function getArray<T_Cons>(cons: T_Cons): InstanceType<T_Cons>[] {
  return cons.map( (c: con) => new con() );
}

let t1: T1 = getOne(T1);
let [t2, t3]: [T2, T3] = getArray( [T2, T3] );
```

Comment: Support for variadic tuple types will arrive with TypeScript 4 (currently in the making): https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39094

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can do this in TS3.1 and above using [mapped array/tuple types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26063).  It's a little easier to get [tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) inferred for [rest parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions) than it is for array parameters, so I'll show that instead:

```
function getVariadic<T extends Array<AnyCon>>(...cons: T): {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends AnyCon ? InstanceType<T[K]> : never
};
function getVariadic(...cons: AnyCon[]): any[] {
  return cons.map((c: AnyCon) => new c());
}

let [t2, t3]: [T2, T3] = getVariadic(T2, T3);
```

Edit: Since TypeScript 4.0 introduced [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) you can also get the compiler to infer tuple types from arrays passed in:

```
function getArray<T extends Array<AnyCon>>(cons: [...T]): {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends AnyCon ? InstanceType<T[K]> : never
};
function getArray(cons: AnyCon[]): any[] {
    return cons.map((c: AnyCon) => new c());
}

let [t2, t3]: [T2, T3] = getArray([T2, T3]);
```

Note how the `cons` parameter is of variadic tuple type `[...T]`, which gives a hint to the compiler to infer that `[T2, T3]` is a tuple instead of an unordered array.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-uVAVUQbUVWq6L4+DM3XYkSjOOjzVicjQ8vx8USSWSE5SBPJCrSpHLyvLmTRWeywFyeQAjPlLGVC05COqqnUSFucijIsryoeYIA)

Comment: Great answer thanks! I don't really need arrays to the rest version is perfectly fine. One final query; what does the ": never" part of the mapped type syntax do exactly?

Comment: Are you familiar with [conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types)?  In this case we know that `T[K] extends AnyCon` is true but the compiler doesn't, so I use a conditional type to say: "If `T[K] extends AnyCon` is true, then produce `InstanceType<T[K]>`; if not, produce `never`".  This makes the compiler happy, and we don't have to worry about the `never ` case because it's not going to happen.

Comment: I am somewhat familiar with conditional types and that makes sense, I just couldn't see how the `never` would work if hit. The fact that it's impossible puts that to rest. I guess there'd be some sort of TS compile issue if the `never` case was ever hit?

Comment: @jcalz would it possible to change `getVariadic` to accept `undefined` as value as well `Array<AnyCon | undefined>`. So that the function can be called as `getVariadic(T2, undefined, T3)` and the result is correctly typed as undefined?