# Inference of argument callback signature as tuple within generic function?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

Following on from [a previous question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54701874/variadic-generic-types-in-typescript) I'm looking to forward a mapping of a generic argument type as parameters to a callback that is passed as a parameter. My desire is to pass in an arbitrary number of constructor functions, use these to construct instances and then forward the instances to a callback.

I have this working currently where the parameter is just an array to the callback, but this is less than convenient syntactically and TypeScript also provides no tooling assistance in verifying that the provided callback has the correct signature. If you take a look at the code below you should see my intent; I want to be able to specify regular parameters for the callback (not an array) and have TypeScript error out if the callback has an incompatible signature.

Can TypeScript do this and if so how?

```
class Component {}
class One extends Component { public a = 1; }
class Two extends Component { public b = 2; }

type CompCon = new (...args: any) => Component;

function receive(one: One, two: Two) { console.log(`one: ${one.a}, two: ${two.b}`) }
function wrongReceive(a: string, b: number) { console.log(`a: ${a}, b: ${b}`) }

function example<T extends Array<CompCon>>(
  callback: (...args: ???) => void,
  ...constructors: T
): void {
  let instances = constructors.map( (c: CompCon) => new c() );
  callback(...instances);
}

example(receive, One, Two); // should be ok
example(wrongReceive, One, Two); // should have typescript compile errors on wrongReceive having wrong signature
example((c: One, d: Two) => {  // should be ok
  console.log(`c: ${c.a}, d: ${d.b}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this. Define `Ctor`:

```
type Ctor<C> = new (...args: any[]) => C;
```

`Ctor<C>` is a type for "something which can be called with `new` and constructs a `C`"

Then you can define `CtorsOf`:

```
type CtorsOf<T> = { [K in keyof T]: Ctor<T[K]> };
```

If `T` is a tuple of types, `CtorsOf<T>` produces a tuple which expects a constructor for each type of `T`. Eg. `CtorsOf<[One, Two]>` would resolve to `[Ctor<One>, Ctor<Two>]`.

Then you can define `example` like this:

```
function example<C extends Component[]>(
  callback: (...args: C) => void,
  ...constructors: CtorsOf<C>
): void {
  let instances = constructors.map(c => new c()) as C;
  callback(...instances);
}
```

`C` is a tuple defining the types of the arguments you expect on your callback, and then from this tuple we derive a tuple of constructors for the `...constructors` argument.

I don't see a way to avoid the type assertion in `let instances = ... as C`. The problem there is that the tupleness of `constructors` is lost through the `.map` operation and the resulting array is of type `Component[]`. I've tried a few variations, but even with something as trivial as `([1, "2"] as [number, string]).map(x => x);` the tupleness of the original array is lost and TS infers a final type for the resulting array of `(string | number)[]`.

Here is a complete example adapted from your original source:

```
class Component {}
class One extends Component { public a = 1; }
class Two extends Component { public b = 2; }

function receive(one: One, two: Two) { console.log(`one: ${one.a}, two: ${two.b}`) }
function wrongReceive(a: string, b: number) { console.log(`a: ${a}, b: ${b}`) }

// Ctor<C> is a type for "something which can be called with new and constructs a C"
type Ctor<C> = new (...args: any[]) => C;

// Given T a tuple of types, CtorsOf<T> produces a tuple which expects a constructor
// for each type of T. Eg. CtorsOf<[One, Two]> would be [Ctor<One>, Ctor<Two>]
type CtorsOf<T> = { [K in keyof T]: Ctor<T[K]> };

// If you uncomment this and use an editor that shows you what Q expands to, you'll see that
// it expands to [Ctor<One>, Ctor<Two>].
// type Q = CtorsOf<[One, Two]>;

function example<C extends Component[]>(
  callback: (...args: C) => void,
  ...constructors: CtorsOf<C>
): void {
  let instances = constructors.map(c => new c()) as C;
  callback(...instances);
}

example(receive, One, Two); // This is okay.
example((c: One, d: Two) => {  // This is okay.
  console.log(`c: ${c.a}, d: ${d.b}`);
}, One, Two);
// example(wrongReceive, One, Two); // Fails to compile.
// example(receive, Two, One); // Fails to compile.

class TwoPrime extends Two { public bPrime = 1; };

example(receive, One, TwoPrime); // This is okay too. TwoPrime is a subclass of Two.

function receivePrime(one: One, two: TwoPrime) { console.log(`one: ${one.a}, two: ${two.b}`) }

example(receivePrime, One, TwoPrime); // This is okay.
// example(receivePrime, One, Two); // Fails to compile. The shape of Two is not compatible with TwoPrime.

const z = ([1, "2"] as [number, string]).map(x => x);
```

Comment: Thanks! The specification of the generic C primarily for the callback and then transforming that to get the constructor types was what I was missing. I kept trying with the constructor types and trying to go to the instance types :P