# Typescript arbitrary number of generic types

Tags: typescript

In Typescript is possible create class with arbitrary number of generic types? like this:

```
class CommonClass<T:any,...R:any[]> { 
    //some stuffs ... constructor, properties....
}

// it's usage...

const myObj = new CommonClass<Obj1,Obj2,Obj3>();
const yourObj = new CommonClass<Obj4,Obj5>();
```

**[EDIT]
following the request for comment from jcalz, i will explain better why it should be useful.**

I'm implementing an API who use CQRS pattern [CQRS - Martin Fowler](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjFxsyAoLPmAhUeD7kGHXTDCYAQFjAAegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmartinfowler.com%2Fbliki%2FCQRS.html&usg=AOvVaw0T9njIrBT3gRuemRKewTl6)
So, Let's imagine a simple application:

Target: A customer will place an order and application will send an email with it's order ticket registration.

Application context: When order request came from a custumer request, the controller must deliver this command **"PlaceOrder"** our command handler 
tell to our model place the order. So orders model after persist data will send an **"OrderPlaced"** event and all listeners will make their jobs, like Mail component for instance who been notified about some "OrderPlaced" and send to customer his ticket.

I'm planing prevent code repetition, for our model for instance, many models will do very common jobs.. [create | Update | delete..] but in some special situations some models will dispatch others events (Here events are classes that will handle another tasks). A CommonModel will be a perfect class for maintain single code base and change few things only needed.

Let's see a pratical example:

```
class CommonModel<T:any,..R:any[]> {
    construct() {}

    create(entity:T) {
       //perform save to our database.

       //here dispatch a common related create event
       this.apply(new R[0](someStuff));

    }
}


import { OrderPlacedEvent } from './some_dir/order.placed';
import { Order } from './some_dir/order.entity';
class OrderModel extends CommonModel<Order,OrderPlacedEvent>{}

class CreateOrderCommand {

    constructor() {super();}

    //method called internally
    handle() { 

       const orderModel = new OrderModel();
       orderModel.create(filledEntity);

    }
}
```

Ok, in above code OrderModel class extends CommonModel and how its Usage is simple no needle any overrides.

```
// But in somewhere Mail has interpected OrderPlaced event and
// make it's job

import { MailSentEvent } from './some_dir/mail.sent';
import { MailLogging } from './some_dir/mail.logging';
import { Mail } from './some_dir/mail.entity';

//Pay attention here we have the 3rd type...
class MailModel extends CommonModel<Mail,MailSentEvent,MailLogging>{
    constructor() {super();}

    //override because we also need use our MailLogging...
    create(entity:Mail){
       super.create(entity);

       //here our extra behavior
       const log = new MailLogging();
       log.write('A new mail was sent somewhere in time');
    }
}
// Triggered by some listener 
class SendEmailCommand {

    constructor() {super();}

    //method called internally
    handle() { 

       const mailModel = new MailModel();
       mailModel.create(filledEntity);

    }
}
```

Above a minimal, obviously non function code example, missing many things 
but well explained

I hope that i'm been clear. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are no [variadic kinds](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453) in TypeScript, but you can probably use [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) instead like `CommonClass<T, R extends any[]>` with `CommonClass<Obj1,[Obj2, Obj3]>` and `CommonClass<Obj4, [Obj5]>` being instances; a [mcve] would be helpful though since you're not doing anything with `T` and `R` for me to show how it would work with tuples.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54701874/9287029

Comment: Thanks! @jcalz i've provided an conceptual application example when i edit it

Comment: Thanks for the effort, although ideally a [mcve] should be actual code that demonstrates your issue.  Right now I don't see how your use case involves anything other than a class hierarchy.  Can you build a small example in code that would benefit from using variadic kinds?  One that specifically does something with the `T` type and `...R` kind in it?

Comment: now we have a minimal code example, i'm really glad for your help effort

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they will add variadic tuple typings as of Typescript v4.0.0:

- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453
- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39094

Its not an exact solution for what you (or other people stumbling on this) may want, bit its definitely going to help.