# Variable number of generic parameters in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a function like this in Typescript:

```
function combine<A, B>(p1: Parser<A>, p2: Parser<B>): Parser<A | B> { … }
```

Is it possible to type it for variable number of type variables (A, B, C, …) and correctly set the result type to `Parser<A | B | C | …>`? I know I can do this by writing the type signatures by hand for different arities:

```
function combine<A>(p1: Parser<A>): Parser<A>;
function combine<A, B>(p1: Parser<A>, p2: Parser<B>): Parser<A | B>;
// …and so on…
function combine(...parsers: Parser<any>[]): Parser<any> { … }
```

Is that the only option?

PS. I was looking at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54701874/variadic-generic-types-in-typescript), but the types are a bit above my head and I don’t know whether it’s the same case or not (the “endless union type” looks like an extra requirement here).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you you can infer the result type based on the arguments. Probably that's what you're trying to achieve

```js
function combine<T extends string>(...ps: Parser<T>[]): typeof ps extends Array<infer R> ? R : never {
    throw new Error('not implemented')
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJwM4QQHgCpQgD2BAOwBMkolgEBLAgcwD4oBeKAbwCgpOpRIAuKAOTxkqAQBoOXJAFcARjwj8MbAL5s2AM2kEAxsEoB7AlB0GAtrOoRM2PIRJkK1egAoAdB7BJ+wlOgx0ANoAugCU-AoGGlBetvjEpACCCAhwIGjUGqhQAEoMAPy5UPwEEABu2exc3AAWCAYA7lClTQCiKQYILgIEBsBQlGZgADYQZoT4RAKhquqmBORQCBAyw-3MphZWLlVcCvwARL6oBxLVMvLgioJwAqpirJKc+1BHiH6nT2RyLwKydyoZmwgA)

---

### Edit:

After reading your comment I realized that you probably want to define the function like this:

```js
// generic extending parser Array
function combine<T extends Parser[]>(...ps: T): typeof ps extends Array<infer R> ? R : never {
    throw new Error('not implemented')
}
```

this way you'd be able to pass a tuple as generic argument to define the type and the position of the arguments

```
const result = combine3<[B, A]>(parserB, parserA)
// typeof result is B | A
```

or don't enforce position, just let ts infer the return type

```
const result = combine(parserB, parserA, parserA, parserC)
// typeof result is B | A | C
```

[examples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJwM4QVAvFA3gKCvqUSALigHJ5lUyAaHAXxxwEsA7YVAMzgGNoBBKBAAeHVgBMksRCjS4CUJAFcARkQikycMgxbsuvaACEhoiBKmVZ2PAWVrwG8ip2M2HBNz5QAwqbGS0lRytvj26po8rnoeXtAAIv7mgVaoNgrhjpri0TgA9HlQAObmqMw8SRJsRVBKrMwA9qyEjjicdTzAjc08DQC2KmwQADwAKpWBggA+UCYzfjPxAHwAFAB0G2BIpKMA2gC6AJSk6g2cUFsTUvwICHAgw2ycaQBKS1AA-FAvUKSsEAA3NLyAjAAAWCAaAHcoP8YQBRW4NBArMisBrAKDMPpgAA2ED65g4OUOunyhRK-wQ5Qm1UUSkgCHUbQ6XSaUF6AyGACYxlcgrJVhs1lsdgdji1IGcLlIRAFrrd7o9WM80G9Pt9frDAcDQoQIdDtQikSi0RisTj8YT9CSyQViqVqRU5ck6WAZGkbncQCzWJ1uhz+oN-gBmPkuiwC1AHIWbbZQUYS07nS4RyaKh5PV7vL4-P46kIKcGQmFwqCIyGm9GY7F4glEiC2xhMXqsJCY93BfikQSYEH4CJQABEqQQQ7oGVUg60uVb7YuHoQRlIJj7esHI8X471mRIzlnTXnndkPlIfjXRayw9H28nDj3ZCiZLnmIQEGUuMxmE5wZG01mqzHqg-A0AuwRGKSOAvlAb4fsA3IYIGXL-Ly-5GIBi4gWBsgQUw9rukgSB0sADQMviUBwFIlJlBUiBFEo1rAFBh6vu+SifiGiE-kMYa7EYoH8PsGHgaBQEIPwpLQbB7HAAALFxQY8SsYn8dhwGiZhGngZJLEwWxn4AKwKchEAhspi6qWJWFWVpJ6kkAA)

Comment: Thank you, but I need the A, B, C types to be unrelated. In other words, I need a function signature similar to `foo<A, B, C, …>(arg1: A, arg2: B, arg3: C, …): A | B | C | …`.

Comment: @zoul I think I've now understood the question, so I've updated my answer. Hope that helped

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to implement it with array of generic types instead of unions. You can do in few ways:

- Create a type and has abbility to do many arrow function implementation

  ```
  type ParserFunc<T extends any[]> = (...args: {
    [P in keyof T]: T[Parser<P>]
  }) => Parser<T[number]>

  const function1: ParserFunc<[string,number]> = (p1, p2) => { ... }  // => Parser<string | number>
  const function2: ParserFunc<[string,string]> = (p1, p2) => { ... }  // => Parser<string>
  const function3: ParserFunc<[string,boolean]> = (p1, p2) => { ... } // => Parser<string | boolean>
  ```
- Create a single standart function

  ```
  function combineParser<T extends any[]>(...args: {
    [P in keyof T]: T[Parser<P>]
  }): Parser<T[number]> {
    // ...
  }

  combineParser(1,'2',true, null) // => Parser<number | string | boolean | null>
  ```