# Reflect the callback parameters to the outer function

Tags: typescript

I have created a simple module called **tryCatchWrap**, which takes a callback function, and wraps it in a try/catch block.

```
type AsyncCb = (...args: any[]) => Promise<any>

export default function tryCatchWrap(cb: Function): AsyncCb {
  return async (...args: any[]) => {
    try {
      await cb(...args)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log((err as Error).message)
    }
  }
}
```

I have an async function which I want to try out on this cool tool:

```
async function testFn(testStr: string) {
  // ... code
}
```

So I wrapped this function in my `tryCatchWrap` method:

```
const testFn = tryCatchWrap(async function testFn(testStr: string) {
  // ... code
})

testFn()
```

Cool, Now I have one problem left. when I hover over the `testFn` variable, I don't see the call signature of `testStr: string`, instead, I see the call signature of the outer function: `...args: any[]`.

How can I reflect the inner interface, so I can see `testStr: string` instead of `...args: any[]` when I hover over the variable `testFn`?

[image]

Comment: Yes, and I forgot to mention, how to reflect the return value as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add some generic type parameters to capture the actual call site argument types:

```
export default function tryCatchWrap<A extends any[], R>(cb: (...a: A) => Promise<R>): (...a: A) => Promise<R | null> {
  return async (...args: A): Promise<R | null>  => {
    try {
      return await cb(...args)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log((err as Error).message)
      /// you could also decide on passing in a default value, or returning an error, or some other way to signal an error
      return null; 
    }
  }
}

const testFn = tryCatchWrap(async function testFn(testStr: string) {
  // ... code
  return 1;
})

let r = testFn("")
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

In the above example I returned `null` in case of error. You could also do other thing, like return `R | Error` ([ex](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AMwIYFcA29noHYDGMAlhHnDFAJ4DCqMBAFgOpSpgA8AgnKDMHgQBnOKjxUA2gF0ANHABKAPgAUBAEYAuOMoB0e1Fq4BKOAF5FcAApQIAW2JDgHJUa279hk+as37j53AAPnAAolA2UBYA3gBQcHBQwDDoUOSoQlSE2no6qFAA5kKeWtZ2Dk7yQaHh0BZm0XHxFNRwsU1NicmpogDuqMTw6u65BUJGjfEAvnAE9EzawOEmbe0zZEIQmMA6mBD5ysqLUKIiYRFGOrbAQkKo+cDjq3AA9K9wVBDoa1gIopgbiGABGISDgZDgYHSQmIeHycBhokBaCw8AAbqhMOhgHJoAkkik8DC4WJeDUoDjjhsrmCYIxFnA+lQKBA4ND8ngMaJyEdoBMOvjukcTtUIgBuOB8yaNKVSmIEdbwfhCGAAMXIpmatDmLDYYGU6UyBDguEIJHBStVeGUFoAypQtMqoETlo03jk1khGp0CXAAIyimKTcYxLbwY4ai1q5QAImjRiAA)) or passing in a default for the error case ([ex](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AMwIYFcA29noHYDGMAlhHnDFAJ4DCqMBAFgOpSpgA8AgnKDMHgQBnOKjxUA2gF0ANHABKAPgAUBAEYAuOMoB0e1Fq4BKOAF5FcAApQIAW2JDgHJXLIBRKDagA1VJnTAWvJGWrr6hibmVjb2js4WAN4AUHBwUMAw6FDkqEJUhNp6OqhQAOZCEVrWdg5OSqlRyamplFRwTc2p6ZnZogDuqMTw6mHFZUJGKc0AvnAE9EzawJ4mHZ0EZEIQmMA6mBClysrLUKIiHl5GOrbAQkKopcCTnakA9O9wVBDoc9+YCKJMFtEMACMQkHAyHAwLkhMQ8KU4PDRCC0Fh4AA3PwBVynbpZPDwxFiXieaC4uBbG6QmCMZZwAZtGAQSnEUp4PyicgnaBTTr43ruMk+bHAADccD5cGmUxlMqSGzwQng-GVADFyKYKNQ6AwWGwwMpcvkCHBcIQSFDVTANcprQBlShaZVQImrKYfIq-JBTAXkACMYqS0zkAAZJkkdvBTlrrbaAETxoxAA))

Comment: Hi, thanks, I tried not to copy your code, and to understand it instead.

Comment: What is the difference between writing: 
`function tryCatchWrap<T extends any[], R>(cb: (...args: T) => Promise<R>): (...args: T) => Promise<R>` and `function tryCatchWrap<T, R>(cb: (...args: T[]) => Promise<R>): (...args: T[]) => Promise<R> {`

Comment: I know it's hard to write code in comments, so here's the two codes: [click me](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEDMFcDsGMBcCWB7ap4CcCeBhAhvLABYDqGeADgDwAqoApgB7z3QAmAzqHtFgNoBdADSgASgD4AFLABGALlCSAdCrwYA5hwU0AlKAC840AAUMyALaIO9KhJ0LlqjVtC6DR0xas2JoAN6gKkqgAL4AUGEgEDAIKGiYuATEZJS0IhLS8opBapragnqGJmaW1rbi9tlOea4F7sVeZb4BQaFhQA)

Comment: @Normal The `...args:T[]` means TS will try to infer an array of the same elements for `T` and it does so based on the first argument resulting in problems for multiple parameters. Using `T` as the parameter for teh rest argument will make TS look at the whole argument list and infer a tuple based on the arg types which is what we need for functions with multiple arguments to work

Answer (score 0):

If you use `any` you are basically disabling typechecking for that part of the code. Instead, you should use generics. The problem is that it's hard to do generic variadic types (maybe check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54701874/variadic-generic-types-in-typescript) to learn more). Here I've just said that you have one argument. If you want to pretend you have multiple arguments, you can use an object with fields. So you would need to write `testFn({ arg1: something, arg2: somethingElse })` instead of `testFn(something, somethingElse)`.

The closest I can get to what you want is this:

```
type Callback<T, U> = (args: T) => U
type AsyncCb<T, U> = (args: T) => Promise<U>

export default function tryCatchWrap<T, U>(cb: Callback<T, Promise<U>>): AsyncCb<T, U | void> {
  return async (args: T) => {
    try {
      await cb(args)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log((err as Error).message)
    }
  }
}

const testFnVoid = tryCatchWrap(async function testFn(testStr: string) {
    // ...code
})

const testFnString = tryCatchWrap(async function testFn(testStr?) {
    return "It works!"
})
  
testFnVoid("lol") // Typescript says `const testFnVoid: (args: string) => Promise<void>`

testFnString(null) // Typescript says `const testFnString: (args: unknown) => Promise<string | void>`
```

Also, notice that you have to assert that the function can be `void` since when you catch an error you don't return a value. So you have to handle the undefined case in order not to get errors, like so:

```
const testFnString = tryCatchWrap(async function testFn(testStr?) {
    return { thisIs: "an example" }
})

async function consume() {
    const result = await testFnString(null)
    // result.thisIs <- typescript raises an error: "Property 'thisIs' does not exist on type 'void'."

    if (result != undefined) {
        console.log(result.thisIs) // This works
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG, this is too complex, I am having really hard times learning these generics. 